# API GATEWAY lambda function { "message": "Not Found" }

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have some error with the API GATEWAY with lambda
[image: Lambda Code]

this is what I did (or tried) basically wanted to make 2 number to sum

I have POST and GET but something happening when i get into the API GATEWAY it just says  { "message": "Not Found" }

my final result that I wanted is to change the lambda to print the sum result to the browser in addition to sending the mail

thanks for anyone who helps

Comment: Did you manually created the API gateway? Did you use any IAC tool to provision the API gateway?

Comment: Can you share with us your API gateway integration? Seems like the request is not reaching the lambda function, did you create any stage in the API gateway?